# PHP starts by obenning the site

Tags: php, html

i made a Newsletter page in HTML. The content is to be entered in a database and it works. But the php code is running by openning the site, so the database is full of empty Entries. Can you help me?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center">
            <form method="POST" style="margin-top: 100px;">
                <div class="mb-3" style="max-width: 400px;">
                    <label for="name" class="form-label">Vorname:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="n   ame" style="background: transparent; border: none; border-bottom: 3px solid #ffad5b;" required>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3" style="max-width: 400px;">
                <label for="mailInput" class="form-label">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="mail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" style="background: transparent; border: none; border-bottom: 3px solid #ffad5b;" required>

                <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">Deine Email wird nicht an Dritte weitergegeben.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault" required>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                      Ich habe habe die <a href="datenschutz.html" style="color: #ffad5b;">Datenschutzbestimmungen</a> <br>
                      gelesen und akzeptiere sie.
                    </label>
                  </div>
                
                <div class="text-center">
                    <button action="database.php" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #ffad5b; border: none; margin-bottom: 100px;">Senden</button>
                </div>
                
            </form>
        </div>
```

**PHP:**

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    
    

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO newsletter (vname,mail) VALUES ('$name','$email')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        $message = "Erfolgreich!";
        } else {
            $message2 = "Fehler!";
        }

    $conn->close();
```

I thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to wrap all your code in an `if` condition that checks if the form was submitted. It should be sufficient just to check if one of the `POST` fields is set.

Answer (score 0):

Change your PHP code to:

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ((isset($_POST['name'])) && (isset(['email'])))
{

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    //here you should do some input validation to increase security and provide user feedback
    $sql = "INSERT INTO newsletter (vname,mail) VALUES ('$name','$email')";

    //you should change you INSERT statement to PDO to prevent SQL injections
    if ($conn->query($sql) === true)
    {
        $message = "Erfolgreich!";
    }
    else
    {
        $message = "Fehler!";
        //use only one/same variable for error message
        
    }

    $conn->close();
}
else
{
    //provide user error message like
    $message = "Fehler! Bitte Eingaben prüfen.";
}

?>
```

Comment: Whoopsie: `isset(['email'])`